# Why L2TP VPN not working on Monterey

Tags: networking, macos, vpn, macos-bigsur

The VPN connection of Big Sur was totally fine. But when I upgraded to Monterey, I could only ping to my office LAN but not use any applications like ssh and connecting to jupyterhub. I checked the log of the VPN, seems that the vpn sent some packages but not received reply. Besides, I could not browser the webpages after the VPN was connected. Here is the log

```
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : l2tp_get_router_address
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : l2tp_get_router_address 192.168.3.1 from dict 1
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : L2TP connecting to server *.*.*.10' (*.*.*.10)...
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : L2TP sent SCCRQ
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : L2TP received SCCRP
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : L2TP sent SCCCN
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : L2TP sent ICRQ
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : L2TP received ICRP
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : L2TP sent ICCN
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : L2TP connection established.
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : L2TP set port-mapping for en0, interface: 11, protocol: 0, privatePort: 0
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : using link 0
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : Using interface ppp0
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : Connect: ppp0 <--> socket[34:18]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:03 2021 : sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x34f57470> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x34f57470> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x34f57470> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <mru 1500> <asyncmap 0xffffffff> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xc4fcc014>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : lcp_reqci: returning CONFACK.
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <mru 1500> <asyncmap 0xffffffff> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xc4fcc014>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x34f57470]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x1 <0d489d39e22c3dccffd541dcb3193e36>, name = ""]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : sent [CHAP Response id=0x1 <20b668eaf63ed8bb1c384ac2fea50f3b>, name = "wangxufan"]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0xc4fcc014]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : rcvd [CHAP Success id=0x1 "Welcome to ."]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : CHAP authentication succeeded: Welcome to .
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::1e91:80ff:fed4:96df>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 20.20.20.1>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : ipcp: returning Configure-ACK
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x1 <addr 20.20.20.1>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x1 <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x2 <addr 20.20.20.2>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 20.20.20.2>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x3 <addr 20.20.20.2>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : ipcp: up
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : local  IP address 20.20.20.2
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : remote IP address 20.20.20.1
Fri Nov  5 15:06:06 2021 : l2tp_wait_input: Address added. previous interface setting (name: en0, address: 192.168.3.143), current interface setting (name: ppp0, family: PPP, address: 20.20.20.2, subnet: 255.0.0.0, destination: 20.20.20.1).
Fri Nov  5 15:06:07 2021 : L2TP port-mapping update for en0 ignored: VPN is the Primary interface. Public Address: 0, Protocol: None, Private Port: 0, Public Port: 0
Fri Nov  5 15:06:07 2021 : L2TP clearing port-mapping for en0
Fri Nov  5 15:06:09 2021 : sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::1e91:80ff:fed4:96df>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:12 2021 : Received protocol dictionaries
Fri Nov  5 15:06:12 2021 : sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::1e91:80ff:fed4:96df>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:12 2021 : Committed PPP store on install command
Fri Nov  5 15:06:15 2021 : sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::1e91:80ff:fed4:96df>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:18 2021 : sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::1e91:80ff:fed4:96df>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:21 2021 : sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::1e91:80ff:fed4:96df>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:24 2021 : sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::1e91:80ff:fed4:96df>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:27 2021 : sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::1e91:80ff:fed4:96df>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:30 2021 : sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::1e91:80ff:fed4:96df>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:33 2021 : sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::1e91:80ff:fed4:96df>]
Fri Nov  5 15:06:36 2021 : IPV6CP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Fri Nov  5 15:06:36 2021 : Received protocol dictionaries
Fri Nov  5 15:06:36 2021 : Committed PPP store on install command
```